# Is ObjectBox pragmatic for multi-vendor saas application in terms of data sync and storage

Tags: synchronization, data-synchronization, objectbox

I am exploring the options to start working on a hotel management app that many hotel owners can download, create an account and use on their front desk. Offline support of ObjectBox makes it an attractive option. But I have this question:

> Lets say a Hotel A lists their rooms in my app, and uses the app to book reservations, track inventory, and generate reports. Let's say Hotel B and C do the same on using their own accounts.

Does data syncing mean that all the data from all accounts (from all the hotels) is automatically synced to when internet is available, does that not mean that all connected devices will download data (by way of syncing) from other users? How does OB decide how much of the data is to be synced?

Answer (score 0):

When using ObjectBox Sync all data is currently shared. Sync will make sure each client has all of the data the server has (and changes of a client are distributed to all other clients).

To handle your use case would require to run a separate Sync server instance for each customer.

Note: there is still [authentication](https://sync.objectbox.io/sync-client#authentication-options) (via shared secret or Google auth).

For more technical details see the [docs](https://sync.objectbox.io/). There is also [a website](https://objectbox.io/sync/) and you can email us to talk about details.